# How can I combine several return type requirements of C++20 constraints into one return type requirement?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Currently, I have implemented the ***[Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator)*** concept (which refers to the [Boost proposal](https://tickcpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tick/traits/is_allocator.html)) using C++20 [**constraints and concepts**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>

template <class A>
concept allocator =
  std::copy_constructible<A> &&
  std::equality_comparable<A> &&
  requires(A a) {
    { a.allocate(0) } -> std::regular;
    { a.allocate(0) } -> std::constructible_from<std::nullptr_t>;
    { a.allocate(0) } -> std::equality_comparable_with<std::nullptr_t>;
    { a.allocate(0) } -> std::random_access_iterator;
    { *a.allocate(0) } -> std::same_as<typename A::value_type&>;
  };
```

You can see there are several *return-type-requirement*s for the same `allocate` function. Is there some way to combine them into one single *return-type-requirement* like the following?

```
{ a.allocate(0) } -> std::regular &&
                     std::constructible_from<std::nullptr_t> &&
                     std::equality_comparable_with<std::nullptr_t> &&
                     std::random_access_iterator;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this particular case, you should follow the concept more closely. The return type of `allocator_traits<A>::allocate` is required to be `allocator_traits<A>::pointer`. So that's what you should test. It is `allocator_traits<A>::pointer` that must satisfy the various constraints of contiguous iterator and nullable pointer.

So the code should look like this:

```
template<typename P>
concept nullable_pointer =
  std::regular<P> &&
  std::convertible_to<std::nullptr_t, P> &&
  std::assignable_from<P&, std::nullptr_t> &&
  std::equality_comparable_with<P, std::nullptr_t>
  

template<typename P>
concept allocator_pointer =
  nullable_pointer<P> &&
  std::contiguous_iterator<P>;

template<typename A>
concept allocator =
  std::copy_constructible<A> &&
  std::equality_comparable<A> &&
  requires(A a)
  {
    { a.allocate(0) } -> allocator_pointer;
  };
```

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot combine type constraints like this, but you can create a named concept

```
template <class A>
concept allocate_result =
    std::regular<A> &&
    std::constructible_from<A, std::nullptr_t> &&
    std::equality_comparable_with<A, std::nullptr_t> &&
    std::random_access_iterator<A>;
```

and use it

```
{ a.allocate(0) } -> allocate_result;
{ *a.allocate(0) } -> std::same_as<typename A::value_type&>;
```

You can also parameterize `allocator_result` by the container type and incorporate the last condition:

```
template <class A, class Cont>
concept allocator_result =
    std::regular<A> &&
    std::constructible_from<A, std::nullptr_t> &&
    std::equality_comparable_with<A, std::nullptr_t> &&
    std::random_access_iterator<A> &&
    std::same_as<typename std::remove_pointer<A>::type, typename Cont::value_type&>;

template <class A>
concept allocator =
  std::copy_constructible<A> &&
  std::equality_comparable<A> &&
  requires(A a) {
    { *a.allocate(0) } -> allocator_result<A>;
  };
```