# C++20 concepts: multiple return type requirements?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to implement a `concept` in which there are multiple return types of the member function.

Ex:

```
template<typename C>
concept Container = requires(C a) {
    {a.begin()} ->
        std::same_as<typename C::iterator> ||
        std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
};
```

The code above is to enforce the return type of `a.begin()` be either `C::iterator` or `C::const_iterator`.

But it does not compile.

Are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I combine several return type requirements of C++20 constraints into one return type requirement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147287/how-can-i-combine-several-return-type-requirements-of-c20-constraints-into-one)

Comment: @康桓瑋 No, the one I'm implementing does not constrain multiple concepts. cpplearner showed the trick.

Comment: For this *particular* case, you should check that it returns an `iterator` concept (probably `forward_iterator`), not a specific member like this.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm referring to the requirements specified here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container.  I first constrain `C::iterator` and `C::const_iterator` to satisfy the concept `LegacyForwardIterator` followed by what I stated in the post. So, basically, I'm doing both ways.

Comment: @PHD: My point is that you shouldn't replicate the exact form of named requirements like that. And indeed nowadays, you shouldn't even require a member `begin` function; rely instead on `ranges::begin`.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not sure how to determine the return type of `begin()` without using the exact member, but with `concept`. And does it mean a class does not require `begin()` when using `ranges::begin()`? If so, there's no point in following that reference.

Comment: @PHD: `ranges::begin` can use ADL to call a free `begin` function, and that is a valid way to provide a `begin` function for a type under Ranges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219554/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-phd).

Comment: @康桓瑋 I think I should have marked this question as duplicate given how Nicol Bolas suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unsugared form.

```
template<typename C>
concept Container = requires(C a) {
    requires std::same_as<decltype(a.begin()), typename C::iterator> ||
      std::same_as<decltype(a.begin()), typename C::const_iterator>;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a concept that tests if the type is one of the container's iterator types:

```
template<typename It, typename Container>
concept is_container_iterator =
    same_as<It, typename Container::iterator> || same_as<It, typename Container::const_iterator>;
```

You can then use that concept in your code: `{a.begin()} -> is_container_iterator<C>;`